# Toast selected toggle buttons

Tags: java, android, android-togglebutton

I have 7 `ToggleButtons` created and one `button`. Each named Monday, Tuesday, ... Sunday.

When I select `("Switch ON")` for example Monday and Thursday, I want to touch a button and display "you have selected Monday and Thursday".

Any ideas how do it on the `MainActivity.java`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by setting onCheckedChangeListener for all the seven toggle buttons and appending it to a string. On click this string could be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ToggleButton toggleButton_Monday;
  private ToggleButton toggleButton_Thursday,toggleButton_wednesday;
  private Button buttonSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toggleButton_Monday=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggleButton_Thursday=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    toggleButton_wednesday=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
    buttonSubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


            if(toggleButton_Monday.isChecked()) {

                result.append("Monday ");
            }

            if(toggleButton_Thursday.isChecked()) {

                result.append("Thursday ");

            }

            if(toggleButton_wednesday.isChecked()) {

                result.append("Wednesday ");

            }
            //Displaying the message in toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You have selected "+result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

}
 }
```

You can do like this.